# How to check if an java native method is implemented?

Tags: java

I want to check implementation of the native method before use it, but I don't know how.

Comment: Aren't you already checking for this at compile time?  I mean, if the native library does not have a method, I would think your IDE would flag it.

Answer (score 1):

If a native method of a class isn't defined for your platform, the classloader will throw an `java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError`. So your test could be

```
try {
  Class.forName("your.class.with.NativeCode");
} catch (UnsatisfiedLinkError e) {
  // the implementation for the methods cannot be linked.

}
```

This code would need to be in an unrelated class that doesn't have any direct dependency to the class with native code. Otherwise this class cannot be loaded as well.